# Switch name node - Hadoop Java api with camel , jms

Tags: hadoop, apache-camel, fs, java

Hi I am using camel to get the messages from the JMS queue, process the message store it in Hadoop using FS java API and then transfer it to another queue

Currently my JMS concurrent is 20. so at one shot camel JMS consumes 20 messages at a time. For every message, I create the fs connection and perform an operation that creates a file and writes a file.

Here is the issue

What i see is sometimes while writing the content to the file, due to some reason my namenode goes down, in this case, I want to switch my name to the active name node

Here is a log I get

[Camel (camel-1) thread #1 a failover occurred since the last call #169 ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPD.getFileInfo over {name_node_address_allias/ip:port}

When I debug it I show Operation category WRITE is not supported in state standby

I want at that time to switch to the active name node

Hadoop Java API Sample code

```
package org.myorg;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;

public class HdfsTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        conf.addResource("path-of-core-site.xml");
        conf.addResource("path-of-hdfs-site.xml");
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://cloudera:8020");
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hdfs@CLOUDERA", "/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);    
        //logic to create a file and write
        //close the cfile and connection
    }
}
```

Comment: _"blah blah in state standby"_ means the NameNode you were connected to has failed over, you need to try the other one.

Comment: Usually it's just a warning, the Hadoop client lib is supposed to handle the switch automatically (but if the failover happened while you were reading/writing, you must catch the error and retry the whole operation)

Comment: Generally speaking, a distributed system must be _expected_ to have failing parts. And to recover, most of the time. It's your job to `try / catch` possible failures or time-outs not managed implicitly inside the client libs, and handle the application-level logic for retries or graceful aborts. Programming is a JOB...   : -0

Comment: Thanks for the comments , currently what is happening is if my name node is in standby and WRITE operation is happening then retryInvocationHandler (hadoop) class keeps on trying on same namenode 14 times (Does someone has any solution to decrease it to 3 to  4 retries ), what i want is at that time switch to the active name name or close the connection create the new one and proceed further from there .

Comment: That's a very different question!! Google for `hdfs-defaults.xml` then zoom to property `dfs.client.failover.max.attempts` and friends (sleep etc.)